# django - POST after Get won't work in the view

Tags: python, django, post, logging, request

I'm trying to write a view which will do two things:
first it will show an empty form, if the request.method is Get.
then it should submit the form into the database, if the method is POST.

the problem is, that when the form is submitted and it should POST stuff, the same view won't run, instead it runs the root url of the project.
here is the log:

(add is the url I've set for this view)

```
[14/Sep/2017 18:27:07] "GET /add HTTP/1.1" 200 1815
[14/Sep/2017 18:27:12] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 1683
```

(add is the url I've set for this view)

and the code looks like this:

```
def add_link(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Form(request.POST)
        ...

    else:
        form = Form()
    return render(request, 'mytemp.html', {'form': form })
```

and here's how the form looks like in the template:

```
    <form action="." method="post">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p><input type="submit" value="Add Link"></p>
    </form>
```

Comment: What does your template look like that contains the form that's being submitted?

Comment: I added it to the question above.

Comment: Show your urls as well please.

Comment: @RezaKeshavarz what if you remove `action="."` altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action is not set correctly:

```
<form action="." method="post">
```

Either leave it completely:

```
<form method="post">
```

Or use `{% url ... %}` to let it point to your current view.

```
<form action="{% url 'yourviewsname' %}" method="post">
```

Please post your `urls.py` for a more detailed answer.